# is Javascript's setInterval loop a resource hog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, intervals

I'm designing an app to run on very low spec machine..and i needed it to be efficient as possible..

I needed to issue around 10 intervals at every second that simply makes an ajax call.. and then does a few add/remove classes and (think of it as SERVER Status monitor)

I know in FLASH (oh good old flash days) having a lot of intervals can cause processor spikes .. so i'm very conservative with issuing setIntervals in AS 2.0  before.

I was wondering if this is the same case with JS? or is it alright for JS to have a bunch of intervals (that does lightweight tasks) running? I noticed a lot of sites do this , even facebook has tons of intervals running, loading scripts, etc..

And oh, for one interval, I wanted to run it at 50ms (it loads as status.php link) ... this ok?

I could probably optimize my interval calls, no problem but i'm just wondering how "heavy" or "lightweight" background intervals are in JS..

Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

10 intervals at every second meaning a call every 100ms should not be an issue in my opinion, but if you ask me I would fire a call every **250ms**.There is not much difference between the two that the user will notice.

Also make sure that there is a mechanism to handle long running response from server in case there is a delay and stop the interval firing if there is drag.

Comment: thanks mate.. and yes i actually coded my own advancedInterval function to avoid multiple calls.. w/o me needing to code conditions..

i basically use a "HOLD_VARIABLE" for every interval i call

but again thanks for clarifying this for me.

Comment: Its pretty standard for an applications polling data and for most of applications who don't use long polling or server push, polling at regular intervals is standard.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of personal feeling, I tend to prefer `setTimeout` over `setInterval` -- to the point I don't use `setInterval` at all.

The issue that you might run into is if one process takes longer than it should -- let me give you an imaginary situation:

```
window.setInterval(takes100msToRun, 50);
window.setInterval(takes50msToRun, 50);
window.setInterval(takes20msToRun, 50);
```

The problem is that the first interval will take longer than it should, so the second two interval requests are now behind and the browser will try to catch up by running them as quickly as then can.  The second interval takes 50ms, -- so its still running behind when the third interval hits.

This creates an ugly situation that can lead to a lot of drag.

On the other hand, if you setTimeout, then you aren't say "Run this every 50 ms", but rather "Run another one of these 50ms from we finish."  (Assuming, of course, that the functions set up another setTimeout to re-execute.)

It is absolute rubbish for things that need good clock timing, but its superior for everything else.

Comment: tnx for the inputs mate. totally get what you mean here .. gratsi!

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout and setInterval will affect performance, but little.

Since there are **lots of** functions triggered/listening/running in the browser.

**Even a tiny operation like move your mouse to vote up for this answer, there are thousands of events got triggered, and tens of functions start running.**

Don't use setInterval. As a matter of fact, the library underscore doesn't use it either.

See how they implement the _.throttle without setInterval.

http://learningcn.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-66

Comment: I don't agree setinterval will cause performance issues. Throttling is used to prevent multiple calls within the interval range and not necessarily a substitute to setInterval. Throttling can be especially useful for rate limiting execution of handlers on events like resize and scroll.